# Implicit conversion from int to varchar

Tags: sql, sybase

```
SET @waveperiod = convert ( varchar,@value ) + convert (varchar,@value2)
```

Is this a valid sql statement in procedure ?

`@waveperiod` is a `varchar(20)`

`@value` and `@value2` are `int`

I am getting an error message: `Implicit conversion from int to varchar`

Comment: I feel like you answered your own question. No, it's not an valid sql statement. It's giving you an error.

Comment: Have you tried CAST, like: SET @waveperiod = CAST(@value as varchar(10)) + CAST(@value2 as varchar(10))

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid syntax in Sybase ASE, see below. But you did not specify your actual database other than just 'sybase' in the tag'...

```
DECLARE  @waveperiod varchar(20)
DECLARE @value int, @value2 int
SET @value = 123
SET @value2 = 456
SET @waveperiod = convert ( varchar,@value ) + convert (varchar,@value2)
SELECT @waveperiod

Result:
 --------------------
 123456
```